# Azure Media Services - FairPlay configuration shows - Certificate validation failed

Tags: openssl, azure-media-services, drm, fairplay, azure-media-player

I have already setup DRM for Widevine and Playready. It is working perfectly.
Now I also want to enable FairPlay. But when I am trying to add the App Certificate to FairPlay Configuration in Content Protection blade in Azure Media Services it does not accept my certificate. 
It shows - **Certificate validation failed!**

I have correctly followed all the steps as per mentioned in the doc:
**Apple FairPlay license requirements and configuration**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/fairplay-license-overview

Here are the steps I have followed:
1) Generate key pair

```
openssl genrsa -aes256 -out privatekey.pem 1024
```

2) Generate CSR

```
openssl req -new -sha1 -key privatekey.pem -out certreq.csr -subj "/CN=FairPlayStreaming/OU=Org/O=OrgName/C=XX"
```

3) Get Certificate and ASK from Apple.

4) Convert the .cer file (DER certificate) to a .pem file (x509 certificate).

```
openssl x509 -inform der -in FairPlay.cer -out FairPlay-out.pem
```

5) Convert the .pem file (FairPlay-out.pem) to a .pfx file (which will be used in Azure media services). For this we need the private key (which was generated for CSR) and privatekey-pem-pass.txt (text file which contains the password of private key).

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out FairPlay-out.pfx -inkey privatekey.pem -in FairPlay-out.pem -passin file:privatekey-pem-pass.txt
```

After this I try to upload the PFX file in Azure but it shows - **Certificate validation failed!**

Can anybody please have a look once and help me understand what I am missing here.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

We managed to raise a support ticket from Azure portal to Azure Media Service Product team.
It turns out they are already aware about this and they are looking into this.
Some customers have also reported same earlier. According to them - Trying different credentials solves the issue.

But anyways, Our requirement was not to use the Azure Portal for this.. rather than we wanted it to finally implement it via C# lib. in our App Service which will run as Encoder service.

So for us it was always working fine from code. We do not need to change anything.

Comment: Hi sir,
Could you pls give me your tutorial for configuring that using C#? Actually, I don't know the meaning of Token Issuer/ Audience. Can that random value?